# How to write a sparql query with variable predicate?

Tags: sparql, rdf

Please have a look at the following example:

```
@prefix : <#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:Bob :score 78 .
:John :score 50 .

:rule1 :condition [
        rdf:subject :score ;
        rdf:predicate :notLessThan ;
        rdf:object 60
     ];
     :condition [
        rdf:subject :score ;
        rdf:predicate :notGreaterThan ;
        rdf:object 80 
     ];
     :rating :passed .

:rule2 :condition [
        rdf:subject :score ;
        rdf:predicate :lessThan ;
        rdf:object 60
     ];    
     :rating :failed .
```

I want to get the following output by spqrql query:

```
 :Bob :rating :passed.    
 :John :rating :failed.
```

here rdf:predicate is changeable by the user, and its value may be:

```
 lessThan, notLessThan, greaterThan, notGreaterThan
```

So how do I write this SPARQL statement based on dynamic predicate?
I don't have any ideas. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: what did you try so far? I mean, you raised so many questions already that you should be capable of starting with something given that you already know `FILTER`, `BIND`, `IF` and all those relevant SPARQL constructs.

Comment: By the way, at some time comes the point where things get complicated if not impossible with a single SPARQL query. Here we already have the problem that all conditions of a rule have to be checked, and there are multiple rules. That's why people invented rule engines and SPARQL 1.1 comes with its own entailment regime.

Comment: Thank you UninformedUser . What rule engine is appropriate for problems like this?  I am a beginner to RDF and Sparql.  Thanks to your help and others, I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does work perfectly :

```
PREFIX : <#>
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

CONSTRUCT {
    ?student :rating ?rating .
} WHERE {
    ?student :score ?score .
    ?rule :rating ?rating .
    OPTIONAL {
       ?rule :condition ?condition .
       ?condition rdf:subject :score .
       ?condition rdf:predicate ?predicate .
       ?condition rdf:object ?object .
       # fails condition
       FILTER (
           ! ( (?predicate = :lessThan && ?score < ?object ) ||
               (?predicate = :notLessThan && ?score >= ?object ) ||
               (?predicate = :greaterThan && ?score > ?object ) ||
               (?predicate = :notGreaterThan && ?score <= ?object )
           )
       )
    }
    FILTER(!bound(?condition))
}
```

and we get the results:

```
:Bob    :rating  :passed .
:John   :rating  :failed .
```

Comment: this cannot work, as I told you, you have to ensure that all conditions of a rule pass. Something that is difficult to achieve in SPARQL and usually done via double negation, i.e. there is no such condition of a rule that does not pass.

Comment: Sorry, UninformedUser, I got the initial data wrong,  I wrote :Bob :score :78.  it should be :Bob :score 78.  I have now corrected the original question . the answer now work well.